# Как в новый пустой массив добавить определённое значение из другого массива?

Tags: java

Например:

```
int[] arr = new int[] {4, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 4, 1, 5, 1, 5, 6};
int[] NewArr = new int[] {};
```

Из массива arr добавить 2 и 3 элемент в массив NewArr, чтобы в новом массиве было только два этих новых элемента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Джаве массив не является динамическим, то есть его размер должен был определен при инициализации. Если вы объявили его пустым, то он останется пустой.
В вашем случае задача решается немного иначе:

```
int[] arr = new int[] {4, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 4, 1, 5, 1, 5, 6};
int[] newArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 2, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы создали массив нулевой длины. В языке Java невозможно изменить размер массива после его создания.

Сначала создайте массив нужного размера:

```java
int[] newArr = new int[2];
```

Потом выполните необходимые манипуляции:

```java
newArr[0] = arr[2];
newArr[1] = arr[3];
```

Если вам нужны динамические массивы, то используйте [Java-коллекции](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Если под добавлением в массив вы подразумеваете нечто вроде newArr.add(5), то обычный массив в Java так не умеет. Если вам нужно что-то добавлять в массив, расширяя его на ходу, для этого стоит использовать класс ArrayList. Например: `ArrayList<Integer> newArr = new ArrayList<>()`, и затем `newArr.add(arr[2]); newArr.add(arr[3])`.

Answer (score 1):

у массива есть свойтво - `length` - его вместимость(размерность)...

```
int[] arr = new int[] {4, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 4, 1, 5, 1, 5, 6};
        int[] NewArr = new int[arr.length];
```

и мы получим новый массив размерностью предыдущего

```
 System.out.println(NewArr.length); // 18
```